# modificar constructor de un jdialog

Tags: arraylist

necesito modificar el constructor de un jdialog
os pongo un ejemplo
para poder pasar un array desde un jframe a un jdialog he visto este ejemplo

desde la ventana principal
// Almacenamos en un array los parámetros para pasarlos al formulario de configuración. (jdialog)

```
double[] array = new double[2];


// Declaramos como atributo de la clase un objeto del tipo DialogoConfiguracion. que es el nombre de la segunda clase
DialogoConfiguracion dialogo;
```

y se crea en el Actionperformed del boton que esta situado en la clase principal

```
// Almacenamos en un array los parámetros para pasarlos al formulario de configuración.
double[] array = new double[2];
```

private void btnConfigActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    // Llamamos al constructor del cuadro de diálogo. Previamente lo hemos debido modificar 
    // añadiéndole los parámetros que necesitemos pasarle. En el ejemplo necesitamos pasar
    // un array de double (esto se podía haber mejorado creando una clase llamada configuración
    // y pasando un objeto de ese tipo).

    dialogo=new DialogoConfiguracion(this,true,array);

    // Mostramos el cuadro de diálogo.
    dialogo.setVisible(true);
```

luego en la clase Dialogoconfiguracion modifican el cosntructor con el array

// Declaramos el array que utilizará el cuadro de diálogo.
    double[] array2;

```
/**
 * Creates new form DialogoConfiguracion
 */

// DEBEMOS MODIFICAR EL CONSTRUCTOR DEL CUADRO DE DIÁLOGO PARA AÑADIR EL ARRAY QUE VAMOS A PASARLE.
// Añadimos el parámetro double[] array.

public DialogoConfiguracion(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal, double[] array) {

    super(parent, modal);

    initComponents();

    this.setTitle("Configuración de IVA y Descuento");


    // Asignamos el array que hemos pasado en el constructor al array que utilizará el cuadro de diálogo.

    array2=array;
```

mi pregunta es la siguiente, como hago para en vez de cargar en la clase del jdialog un array cargar un ArrayList

Comment: Estaría faltando mas código, pero de todas formas intenta reemplazando tu array por un ArrayList, siguiendo las indicaciones que dejo en mi respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Importar**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

**Declaración del ArrayList**: `List<Double> lista;`

**Inicialización**: `lista =new ArrayList<>();`

**Agregar valores al ArrayList**:

Usas el método `add()`.

Ejemplo: agrego `2.55` y `10`

```
lista.add(2.55d);//fijate que el separador de decimales es `.` y luego se pone `d` por que es un double
lista.add(10d);
```

El constructor de **DialogoConfiguracion** te va a quedar así:

```
public DialogoConfiguracion(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal, List<Double> list)
```

Para **acceder al valor de cada índice** del ArrayList:

Usas método `get()`:

Por ejemplo vamos a mostrar por consola los elementos que agregué:

```
System.out.println("lista en índice 0: "+lista.get(0));
System.out.println("lista en índice 1: "+lista.get(1));
```